# Regular Expression three characters in sequence and not repeated in the string

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I tried to solve the problem below using regular expression, but couldn't (end up using other approach):

http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13006&rd=15846

Given a string, you must check if contains the characters `C`, `A` and `T` in this order, and that there's only one occurrence of each. It can be other characters between these characters.
Ex:

```
CTA -> false
XCYAZTX -> true
ACBBAT -> false
CATT -> false
CCAT -> false
CAAT -> false
CAT -> true
```

So, it would be:

```
public String getAnswer(String S) {
   if(S.matches("pattern???")) return "Possible";
   return "Impossible";
}
```

Does someone know a pattern to use and can share please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use a pattern like this:

```
^[^CAT]*C[^CAT]*A[^CAT]*T[^CAT]*$
```

Comment: Thank you. Just waiting pass the time limit, so I can check your answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

This regex should work for you:

```
"(?m)^[^CAT]*C[^CAT]*A[^CAT]*T[^CAT]*$"
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mY2tI5)

Comment: Thank you. It also works. Alcanzar answered a little bit faster. That's why I checked his answer as correct.

Comment: Yes it is fair to check his answer. I started creating fully working demo and took more time to write my answer and eventually posted my answer 17 sec late :)

Comment: +1 for the fully working demo *and* correct regex. A well spent seventeen seconds!